# Updating Values In PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, onclick

I have a php array for two values, and I would like to output an array value when a button is clicked.
Is there a way?

Here's a short example to give you an idea of what I'm looking for

PHP array:

```
$values = array(
  "variable_1" => $a + $b,
  "variable_2" => $a,
);
```

Button:

```
<button type="button" onClick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

JavaScript function:

```
function myFunction() {
   //code to have affect for php values
}
```

Outputting Variable_1 from the array if button was clicked/

```
<p>
<?php  
   foreach ($values as &$value) {
          echo $value; //echo variable_1 if button was clicked
    }
?>
</p>
```

I'm not too savvy in PHP, any help or solutions will be appreciated!

Comment: Read web-basics please and learn difference between client and server.

Comment: I understand the fundamentals in both server-side and client-side languages.

Comment: Where are variables $a and $b defined?

Comment: Then move along and read about ajax

Comment: I'm sorry, we can say variables $a and $b are 1 and 2 respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work the way you tried it, because you obviously cannot execute php code in the browser.

What you can do to achieve the same thing is to "transfer" the php-variables to javascript by simply printing it's values:

```
// in a php-script, but outside of php-tags
<script>
var phpvar = <?php echo $a; ?>;
</script>
```

Now you can work with that values (not the variable itself!!) in javascript to display it at desired actions:

```
// still in html/js
<script>
function myFunction() {
   alert(phpvar);
}
</script>
```

Note, that you cannot change/manipulate php-variables...

Comment: Best solution for what I'm looking to do. Thank you Jeff!